# Why Splash window takes time to come up in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have reffered one sample posted in codeproject

[sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFsplashscreen.aspx)

I tried this sample but splash screen taked 6 to 7 seconds to come up.

I have core 2 duo Processor 2.80GHz with 2 GB ram.

I also refferred to msdn article but it cannot help.

I have to show the splash screen immediately as user click my executable to launch. My application takes time to load as it has ribbon window control and third party conrols.

Please let me know if anybody knows good sample on splash screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will always be some delay before the splash screen can be displayed. Especially in a .Net app which might have to load the .Net framework etc as well.

If you do really need to show a splash screen as soon as possible the easiest way might be to create a tiny unmanaged app (I'd suggest in C++) that does nothing more than to display the splash screen and then starts up your real app and then removes the splash screen.

Comment: It's unfortunate but I agree, there really isn't a faster way to display the splash screen.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have a performance problem, you should use a profiler to work out where the time is being spent - if you guess, you're likely to guess incorrectly.

But some general help:

- An alternative splash screen technique http://www.olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/A-better-WPF-splash-screen.aspx
- Make sure that you're initialising as little of you application as possible before your splash-screen is displayed - does your application class have a lot of static data which is bringing in a lot of code?
- Have you tried the built-in splash screen mechanism?

Comment: I have not tried built in splash screen mechanism. Please let me know if you have some useful links for that.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/08/12/what-s-new-in-wpf-3-5-sp1-splash-screen-to-improve-perceived-startup-perf.aspx

Comment: I have tried splash screen mechanism, but it can be applied to bitmap images only. However, I have to show custom dialog for that.

Comment: Are you showing a WPF dialog as your splash screen?  That might be very slow indeed.  If you just need a bit of changeable text, could you compose a bitmap using System.Drawing and show that?  Otherwise, you just need to work on what your app's doing before it shows the splashscreen, and make that happen later